# How to exit from a python session on channel hangup .?

Tags: mod-python, freeswitch

My scripts keeps on giving me error log

> Channel is hungup and application 'curl' does not have the zombie_exec flag

Can anybody tell my how to exit session on channel hangup ?

Answer (score 0):

For calls with dialplan add to dialplan

```
<action application="set_zombie_exec"/>
```